# Proguard - Obfuscate inner packages while keeping outer packages

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-productflavors

I am developing an android application that uses my own custom framework/jar/SDK. Let us assume the SDK package name is `com.vrs.fm` within this main package, there are N no of subpackages and classes. My application package is `com.vrs.app` due to historic reasons.

While enabling proguard on my custom `vrs` SDK, i need to keep classes under package `com.vrs` so I added below proguard rules.

```
 -dontwarn com.vrs.**
-keep class com.vrs.** { *; }
```

This keeping my application code also un-obfuscated.

Now I would like to know is there any way/rule, that I can obfuscate classes under `com.vrs.app` packages but keeping classes under `com.vrs.fm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an exclusion rule to exclude certain sub-packages from being kept:

```
-keep class !com.vrs.app.**, com.vrs.** { *; }
```

If there are certain parts in com.vrs.app that still need to be kept explicitly, you can then add additional keep rules as needed like that:

```
-keep class com.vrs.app.xxx.yyy { xxx; }
```

Comment: -keep class !com.vrs.app.**, com.vrs.** { ; } is not working. However -keep class !com.vrs.app.*, com.vrs.** { *; } working but obfuscating only classes under com.vrs.app but not sub packages com.vrs.app.XXX.

Comment: Did you use the exact same rule as in the answer? I would be surprised if it does not work. Check if you do not have another rule that might also keep com.vrs.app.**.

Comment: Yeah, I used same rule as in the answer. Probably other proguard rules in my file might stopped it.